# Difference between (Person)o.getName() and ((Person)o).getName()

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors

I have class Person:

```
class Person{
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

, and I wanted to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = new Person("Person a");
    String personName = (Person)o.getName();
}
```

What I get is compile error: *Cannot resolve method 'getName' in 'Object'*. How it didn't work when I technically casted `o` to `Person`?

After some experimenting, I changed code to `String personName = ((Person)o).getName();`, which compiles fine. Unfortunately, I still don't understand how different it is to previous attempt.

Comment: `(Person)o.getName();` - this will try to cast the result of `o.getName()` to `Person` whereas `((Person)o).getName();` will cast `o` to `Person` before calling `.getName()` method on `o`.

Comment: with `(Person)o.getName()` it's casting `getName()` which is s `String` to `Person`

Comment: *How it didn't work when I technically casted o to Person?* You did not. You attempted to cast `o.getName()` to `Person`. `o` is an `Object`, so that didn't work. But `getName()` returns a `String`, so if the object resolved that would still fail. `Person o = new Person("Person a"); String personName = (Person)o.getName();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast operator has a lower precedence that a method call.

`((Person)o).getName()` means you cast `o` to a `Person`, and then call `getName()` on it.
`(Person)o.getName()` means you call `getName()` on `o`, and then cast the result to a `Person`. Since `o` is an `Obejct` and doesn't have a `getName()` method, this line of code won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

In the following statement

```
(Person)o.getName();
```

`o.getName()` returns a `String` which you are trying to cast to `Person` and thus it will fail compilation even if `o` had a method called `String getName()` which is anyway not there in your case because `o` is a reference of `Object`.

In the following statement

```
((Person)o).getName();
```

You are casting `o` to `Person` and then getting the name from it by calling `getName()` on it,.